# Return property of node without expanding search/query pattern

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

- I have a node `a` which is connected to multiple nodes `b`.
- Nodes `b` represent test results which are categorized by their `genericDocumentId`. The tests are performed multiple times until all are passed. This is why there are multiple nodes `b` with the same value for `genericDocumentId`. Their only difference is the property value of `createdOn` and `testedVersion`.
- I used the `max()` function to return only the lastest test result for each `genericDocumentId`. The query works fine BUT I also need the value of the according `testedVersion` of a test result in the returned line!

```
MATCH (a:Software)
WITH a OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[:ISVERIFIED]-(b:Test)
RETURN a.objId, b.documentId, max(b.createdOn)
```

→ **3 hits**

- When I add the property, the number of hits goes up because the query now also respects the `testedVersion` property and creates new buckets for it.

```
MATCH (a:Software)
WITH a OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[:ISVERIFIED]-(b:Test)
RETURN a.objId, b.documentId, max(b.createdOn), b.testedVersion
```

→ **7 hits** (because `b.testedVersion` expands the pattern and creates new buckets)

***What I need is a way to add properties to already filtered lines and DOESN'T affect the query!***

I tried `WITH` to 'freeze' the results before adding the `testedVersion` property in `RETURN` but this doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```
MATCH (a:Software)
WITH a 
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[:ISVERIFIED]-(b:Test)
WITH a.objId AS obj_id, b.documentId AS doc_id, b
ORDER BY obj_id, doc_id, b.createdOn DESC
RETURN obj_id, doc_id, collect(b)[0] AS most_recent
```